# Java back-end check IP and block

Tags: java, spring, authentication, passwords, ip

I have REST API. Front Vue and back Java + Spring. Where I can find any example how to check IP address of request for my login page to make it save? I need to block IP address on Back End if there was 10 wrong attepts of login, for example.

Thanks to all in future, for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this code.

```
String remoteAddr = "";
        if (request != null) {
            remoteAddr = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
            if (remoteAddr == null || "".equals(remoteAddr)) {
                remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
            }
        }
```

You can find the IP address from your request object into your Rest API.

Comment: @EugeneShamkin, I'm glad I could help.